# empty span in IE occupies space

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, space

when inspecting elecment, I noticed the following empty span

```
<span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span>
```

in order to not having it occupy any space, I set the following style

```
span.x-tree-node-indent
{
    left:0px;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

In Chrome, I got what I wanted even without the addional styles. But in IE, I still can see a block of space over there. Any reasons? and how to fix that?

Comment: Side note -- you don't have to specify `px` after a zero.  Zero is zero, regardless of measurement. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `display:none`?

```
span.x-tree-node-indent {
    display: none;
}
```

That should work the same everywhere but I can't check IE right now, [`display:none`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop):

> This value causes an element to not appear in the formatting structure (i.e., in visual media the element generates no boxes and has no effect on layout). Descendant elements do not generate any boxes either; the element and **its content are removed from the formatting structure entirely**. This behavior cannot be overridden by setting the 'display' property on the descendants.
>
> Please note that a display of 'none' does not create an invisible box; **it creates no box at all**. [...]

Emphasis mine.

Here's a quick example if you want to check for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZrzWz/

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced what you're describing in IE6, 7 & 8.

You have to set the **line-height** to zero as well. This usually works for inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce it here. Here is my code:

```
span.x-tree-node-indent
{    
    left: 0px;    
    width: 0px;    
    height: 0px;    
    margin: 0px;    
    padding: 0px;
}

<BODY>
<P>left<SPAN class="x-tree-node-indent"></SPAN>right</P>
</BODY>
```

I see the one word "leftright" without any space inbetween in my IE9.

Depending upon what kind of behavior you want to achieve you may use the attributes `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, display: none will cause the item to take itself entirely out of the the layout. visibility: hidden will not; that is, if you had a 20px by 20px block, that block of space would continue to occupy the space even if it is hidden.

You can also set the display to block, border to none and whitespace

A few other items would be helpful to know - in order for anyone to answer this question with more than the display: none (which will work if all you are wanting to do is have it taken out of the space).

1. What version of IE are you referencing? In no way are the all the same.
2. What is the purpose of the span, if in fact you do not want it to be visible?
3. What doctype is your HTML? Depending, for IE there could be quirks mode involved, you may have the option of using an IE specific meta tag, telling it to render in IE7 mode etc.

For number two, if you are simply wanting to have have an indent as the name implies, then you can use the CSS text-indent: 10px (or whatever). If you have other reasons for it, there are options such as setting margins, padding on the containing area. In other words, semantically, why is this span there when there is no visibility and so on? Which then leads to have you tried other elements etc.